# Close Reasons: “What if ______ happened?”

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Per the Help Center: [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)

> **To prevent your question from being flagged [and possibly removed](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-questions), *avoid* asking subjective questions where …**
>
> - ...
> - you are asking an open-ended, hypothetical question: “What if ______ happened?”
> - ...

Currently I personally deal these questions on quite a regular basis, and it seems that they're getting more frequent; some recent examples:

- [If The Flash travels back in time and changes it, is there still a Flash in the future to travel back?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/78635/if-the-flash-travels-back-in-time-and-changes-it-is-there-still-a-flash-in-the) (Deleted question; only visible to high-rep users)
- https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/77397/what-would-have-happened-if-the-valar-came-to-numenor-to-stop-the-rebellion
- https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/77197/how-would-robb-stark-handle-the-white-walker-threat
- [What if Saruman sent an army to attack Sauron](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/73961/what-if-saruman-sent-an-army-to-attack-sauron) (Deleted question; only visible to high-rep users)

I'm aware that “What if ______ happened?” is [generic boilerplate text that's present on all SE sites](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask), but it seems particularly applicable to this site owing to it's nature: dealing with speculative works in the first place would tend to invite this kind of question moreso than for other sites.

Given this consideration, are these questions of sufficient volume to merit a custom close reason?

Comment: Please note that I'm **NOT** advocating a blanket ban on such questions; [this is an excellent example of what is IMO the right way to go about it](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/78641/is-there-any-information-about-how-alphas-would-have-continued-had-it-not-been).

Comment: I wouldn't mind if there is a specific close-reason - it can help deter those types of Qs. But just out of interest, is there anything in particular wrong with "Primary opinion-based"?

Comment: @Mooz - it doesn't seem explicit enough in this case.  Having "what if" as a close reason sends a clearer signal that this kind of question is off-topic, and doesn't potentially invite argument or denial from the OP.  If a question class is regular enough and if you're copy/pasting the same text as a comment every time in order to explain your VTC, then it signals that something is missing.

Comment: "`If a question class is regular enough and if you're copy/pasting the same text as a comment every time in order to explain your VTC, then it signals that something is missing.`" That's a very interesting point!

Comment: I should add that other SE sites have custom close reasons which could be handled by POD too; e.g this from [gamedev](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/): 'Questions about "how to get started," "what to learn next," or "which technology to use" are discussion-oriented questions which involve answers that are either based on opinion, or which are all equally valid'; so precedence does exist.

Answer (score 12):

I think the implication of the caveat against "what if x happened?" questions is that they should only be asked if they're **supportable** (e.g. that there are sufficient in-universe reasons to think that *something would have happened had something else not happened* or if there are good reason to presume that there will be out-of-universe sources to draw on such as Director interviews). They should be neither open-ended nor require *large* leaps into the hypothetical.

**Good**

> **Q.** *Would Yavin have been destroyed if Luke hadn't blown up the Death Star?*
>
> **A.** *Yes, almost certainly.* It was **about to happen** when Luke blew it up.

---

**Bad**

> **Q.** *Would Yavin have been destroyed if **Leia** had been taken by Obi-Wan?*
>
> **A.** Deeply unclear. No canon reference support this version of events.

The irony is that it's not always possible for a non-specialist to tell the difference and often it doesn't become clear that an answer is possible until after the question is closed.

Comment: Proposed close wording: "Okay, do you have any reason to think this aside from just pulling it out of your ass?"

Comment: +1. Logic-based answers are acceptable, but any answer to your second example question wouldn't be much better than fanfic.

Answer (score 2):

Speaking from personal experience, I did ask one *What would have happened if* question.

[What would have happened if Snape had died in absence of Harry](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/41068/what-would-have-happened-if-snape-had-died-in-absence-of-harry)

In that question, I wanted to know only the in-universe explanation.
As in, did Dumbledore and/or Snape had a backup plan for giving Harry those memories. But seeing that no evidence existed, I turned to see whether
JK Rowling had answered this *What if* question in her later interviews. Apparently, she hadn't.

There in lies my point. What if my intention with my *What if* question was really what-if parallel universe answers? Then that question should/would have been
closed as primarily opinion based. But then what if JK Rowling had answered the question in one of her interviews. Would the question still be primarily 
opinion based? I suppose not.

**TL;DR;** So, I would not close a *What if* parallel-universe scenario question if it is answered by the author. 
Absolutely no question of closing a *What if* in-universe question.