# Correct close reason for 'discussions'

Tags: discussion, closing-questions

One of the types of question listed on the [don't ask](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) page is;

> “I would like to participate in a discussion about ______”

This is quite similar to the hypothetical [what if](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6382/close-reasons-what-if-happened) questions.

I want to make sure I am picking the right close reason, as getting it right and consistent helps everyone.

It seems as if people generally go for Opinion Based for this sort of thing, though given the presence on the don't ask page I would want to go for 'off topic'.

Is there any guidance and does it make any difference?

Comment: With that most recent Star Trek Theology, you could have probably hit it with *'low quality',* *'too broad'* and *'unclear what you're asking'* as well

Answer (score 4):

A discussion by its very nature is going to be too broad and opinion based and that is the reason they don’t fit on the Stack Exchange platform. So you can really choose “Too broad” or “Primarily opinion based” to close a discussion question. I’m essentially looking at the question and finding which one is most appropriate for that specific question. But either or are fine. If you want to state exactly why you’re closing it as such, you can always leave a comment.

There is also “Unclear what you’re asking”, this doesn’t really fit a discussion question in general but can fit to a specific one if you can’t actually understand the question. Sometimes a “question” will just be a wall of text with no actual question in it. It’s probably the starting point for a discussion but as there isn’t any questions in it use the unclear close reason.